# Webpack angular 4 file-loader

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm using [angular-starter](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter).

Right now I'm trying to deploy to a test server. My problem is with the images located at `src/assets/img`.

My angular 4 code (component and view):

```
// Component
public ngOnInit() {
  this.logoUrl = require('../../assets/img/co-logo.png');
}

// View
<img flex src="{{logoUrl}}" alt="Logo">
```

Till here I don't have any issue.

My problem is understanding the behavior of webpack.

I've file-loader installed and I've added this piece of code (and tried a lot of others options) to webpack.common.js:
Have tried with this options:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        outputPath: '/assets/img/',
        publicPath: '/',
        name: '[hash]_[name].[ext]',
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

The output seems not bad at all, I get this:

```
 » app  
  » dist  
   » assets  
    » img  
    - b1249ef43aea4c57bcc7782f6a0ebb99_co-logo.png
```

**The issue**

When loading the page, if I check the url of the image, it only retrieve me this:

```
/app/dist/01b401fa5bdbfdc4e3daf75d72fa76b9.png
```

I was expecting something like:

```
/app/dist/assets/img/b1249ef43aea4c57bcc7782f6a0ebb99_co-logo.png
```

I've tried, at least, with this parameters:

```
publicPath: '/assets/img/'
name: '/assets/img/[hash]_[name].[ext]'
```

Can anyone help me on this? I'm struggling with this since yesterday :/

Thank you all!

Edit: [webpack code](https://pastebin.com/YRxUCQNn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to make things clear and simple while resolving the issue

1. Make sure webpack config has `output.path` pointed to the
   destination folder. I believe its `app` folder in your case. Do note
   that `output.path` takes absolute path i.e use `path` module.
2. Take out `publicPath` in `file-loader` till we resolve the issue.
3. Use relative path for `file-loader`'s `outputPath` i.e. `assets/img`

Once you do those changes, things should work as expected. Then you can try putting back `publicPath` for `file-loader` depending on your need.

In general, i wouldn't use `publicPath` unless i have different environments to be taken care for ex. prod and dev. But thats just me.

Comment: Hello.
 `output.path = helpers.root('dist')`
 `{
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                outputPath: 'assets/img/',
                name: '[hash].[name].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        },`

but still, with this ` ` I now get `assets/img/b1249ef43aea4c57bcc7782f6a0ebb99.co-logo.png` instead of `app/dist/assets/img/b1249ef43aea4c57bcc7782f6a0ebb99.co-logo.png`

Thanks.

Comment: It worked last time I was on it but now I still getting the last comment problem :/

Comment: Hmm, please edit the original post to include your current full webpack config.

Comment: Hello. Is at the end of the first post. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the configuration you have attached is a partial config. There are other configuration options being merged at the build time. Nevertheless, the config of `file-loader` in that file works as expected when tested. The next thing to see is to find out the effective webpack configuration after merging. Can you 1. add `console.log(JSON.stringify(module.exports(), null, 2));` at the end of the same file. 2. Run webpack build 3. Have a look at the effective webpack config that it logs to console. If i have to guess, there must be some override during merge.

Comment: Hi Rakesh. Thanks for your time.
1. https://pastebin.com/pPM7aFtb
2. https://pastebin.com/6J0GSLAa
3. Will take a look now.

thank you :)